# WP_NAV_MENU does not work including my @Media Queries

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

** Original Navbar**

*This is the structure of my actual navbar which includes a hamburger menu dropdown in mobile size. This doesn't work anymore when I try to make my own custom theme in Wordpress. Somehow the css works partly but the function does not use my JavaScript.
I tried a walker menu (see below) but it still does not work. *

```
   <nav class="navbar">

       <div class="container">
           <h1 class="logo"> <?php the_title(); ?> </h1>

           <div class="hamburger">
               <div class="line1"></div>
               <div class="line2"></div>
               <div class="line3"></div>
           </div>
       
           <ul class="nav">
               <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="">About</a></li>
               <li><a href="">Location</a></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </nav>
```

**Here my funcions.php**

```
   function demo1_menus(){

     $locations= array(
        'primary' => 'Desktop primary top navbar',
        'footer' => 'Footer Menu items'
    );

    register_nav_menus($locations);
}
add_action('init', 'demo1_menus');
```

**Here my header.php**

```
<?php
   wp_nav_menu( 
       array(
            'menu' => 'primary', 
            'container' => '', 
            'theme_location' => 'primary',                         
            'items_wrap' => '<ul id="" class="nav">%3$s</ul>',
            'walker' => new Demo1_Walker_Nav_Primary()
       )
   );
?>
```

**Here the walker**

- Can someone tell me why its not working or provide me another solution to my problem please*

```
<?php

class Demo1_Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker_Nav_Menu{

    function start_lvl( $output, $depth ){

        $indent =  str_repeat("\t", $depth );
        $submenu =($depth > 0) ? 'sub-menu' : '';
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"nav$submenu depth_$depth\">\n";
    }
    

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth=0, $args = array(), $id=0 ){
        
        $indent = ( $depth) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $li_attributes = '';
        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;


        $classes[] = ($args->has_children) ? 'nav' : '';
        $classes[] = ($item->current || $item->current_item_anchestor) ? 'active': '';
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        if($depth && $args->has_children){
            $classes[] = 'nav li';
        }

        $class_names = join(' ',apply_filter('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes ), $item, $args) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"';

        $id =apply_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'.$item->ID, $item, $args);
        $id = strlen($id) ? 'id="' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . '>';

        // Link attributes.
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ' class="nav' . ( $depth > 0 ? 'line1' : 'line2' ) . '"';
         
        // Build HTML output and pass through the proper filter.
        $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
            $args->before,
            $attributes,
            $args->link_before,
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
            $args->link_after,
            $args->after
        );
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    

        function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
            $output .= "</li>\n";
        }
                
    }

}


?>
```

Comment: Why do you need your own navwalker, if you are trying to re-create the same thing?

Comment: Hi CBroe, I thought in order to make my navbar customizable on the dashboard I need to convert all my classes into php functions. Isn't it the case? I actually want to convert my web template into a CMS in Wordpress. Is there a easier way ?